# ibm_db.execute- how to get the result set

Tags: python, db2, db2-luw

Newbie working with db2. Developing a python script using ibm_db package. I have a select query where i am binding params using ibm_db.bind_param(stmt, 1,param1). and then doing a result = ibm_db.execute(stmt). How can I get the results from the query. the documentation is scarce on this topic. Would appreciate any example code.

Answer (score 1):

After  `ibm_db.execute(stmt)` you need to fetch data from a result
try this:

```
data = ibm_db.fetch_assoc(stmt)
```

Fetch data from a result set by calling one of the fetch functions.

`ibm_db.fetch_tuple`:   Returns a tuple, which is indexed by column position, representing a row in a result set. The columns are 0-indexed.

`ibm_db.fetch_assoc`:   Returns a dictionary, which is indexed by column name, representing a row in a result set.

`ibm_db.fetch_both`:    Returns a dictionary, which is indexed by both column name and position, representing a row in a result set.

`ibm_db.fetch_row`: Sets the result set pointer to the next row or requested row. Use this function to iterate through a result set.

Answer (score 0):

Study the examples for fetching result-sets in Python with ibm_db, that are in the Db2 knowledge center online at this [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.python.doc/doc/t0054388.html)